# "undefined reference to '_rpl_*'" errors during cross-compilation of gettext

Tags: cross-compiling, gettext, mingw-w64

I have entered the brave world of cross-compilation. I am currently trying to get [`gettext 0.18.2`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) to compile with Mingw-w64 on Ubuntu 12.04. Here is what the configure command looks like:

```
GNULIB_TOOL=../gnulib/gnulib-tool \
CXX="i686-w64-mingw32-g++" \
am_cv_func_iconv_works=yes \
./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 \
            --prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32
```

There are a few things to note in the (rather long) invocation of the configure script:

- `gettext` requires `gnulib-tool`, which is stored in a directory `gnulib` one level above the source tree.
- For some bizarre reason, the configure script can't find Mingw-w64's C++ compiler, so I explicitly provide it.
- The configure script determines whether `iconv` is installed and working correctly by actually compiling a simple example and trying to run it. This obviously doesn't work because the target executables won't run on Ubuntu. So I manually inform the configure script that iconv is installed and works.

After configure runs, I execute `make`, which runs for a very long time and fails at the linking stage:

```
Creating library file: .libs/libgettextpo.dll.a.libs/write-po.o: In function `wrap':
gettext-tools/libgettextpo/../src/write-po.c:963: undefined reference to `_rpl_memchr'
./.libs/libgnu.a(strstr.o): In function `two_way_long_needle':
gettext-tools/libgettextpo/str-two-way.h:339: undefined reference to `_rpl_memchr'
gettext-tools/libgettextpo/str-two-way.h:391: undefined reference to `_rpl_memchr'
./.libs/libgnu.a(strstr.o): In function `two_way_short_needle':
gettext-tools/libgettextpo/str-two-way.h:234: undefined reference to `_rpl_memchr'
gettext-tools/libgettextpo/str-two-way.h:268: undefined reference to `_rpl_memchr'
./.libs/libgnu.a(vasnprintf.o): In function `max_room_needed':
gettext-tools/libgettextpo/vasnprintf.c:1699: undefined reference to `_rpl_strnlen'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What could possibly result in those errors?

---

**Edit:** I get a little further by adding the following environment variable to `configure`:

```
gl_cv_func_memchr_works=yes
```

Now I just get:

```
.libs/libgettextpo.dll.a./.libs/libgnu.a(vasnprintf.o):
  vasnprintf.c:(.text+0x1260): undefined reference to `_rpl_strnlen'
```

Comment: Please try the following: 1) make sure you have a "memchr.o" object file, 2) try the build debugging suggestions in this link: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.gnulib.bugs/21603

Comment: @paulsm4: 1) Yes, this file exists. 2) I can confirm that my output matches his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **finally** got the stupid thing to compile by appending the following options to the configure script:

```
gl_cv_func_memchr_works=yes
ac_cv_func_strnlen_working=yes
```

(Though it only compiles on Win32 at the moment.)